# Сдвиг внутри ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, анимация, view, imageview

Не могу найти как заставить изображение внутри ImageView съехать вниз, так что бы все что выходит за переделы Imageview пропадала

Comment: А какой смысл действия?

Comment: Если мне нужно сделать анимацию, летящего корабля с одного угла в другой